# Best practice for Google Analytics on a mobile site

Tags: google-analytics, mobile

I have a new mobile site which sites on `m.`, `m.example.com`

What is the best method for integrating it's Google Analytics data with the existing data I have.

I want them together so I can easily see total visits for example. But then would like to segment them again to see how much traffic is going to each domain.

Is this possible, if so how?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Google Document "Tracking Multiple Domains - Web Tracking (ga.js)", specifically "[Tracking Across Multiple Domains and Sub-domains](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite)".

Comment: Thanks @initall looks like I just need the same code on both, with the same value for '_setDomainName' and `true` for '_setAllowLinker' ?

Comment: You can relax to only _setDomainName('.example.com'). The _setAllowLinker is just for the examples where they link to and between different toplevel domains, as the cookie information (which is what setDomainName sets) is otherwise lost.